# XML error parsing attribute name

Tags: xml, parsing, google-sheets, attributes

I´ve just downloaded a google spreadsheet add-on: Export Sheet Data as I need to create an XML file to the simplest database ever.
Header, and then the relevant records in the following rows: values and strings.
After exporting which is said to be successful, it opens in my browser but after downloading it the file downloaded cannot be opened, it says: 
"This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 14: error parsing attribute name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."
which is strange because I do not even have 14 columns.

Obviously I´m not a programmer just an ordinary person wanting to create an XML file with a simple tool. Unfortunately the add-on has no forum where I could get help.
This what I see after exporting, in which  comes by itself but I can give a different name if I want within the add-on,  is the name of the sheet within the file I´m exporting from. The headers are between the <> signs and the actual value in the middle:

```
    <Data>
      <Avdragfil>
<1>
  <Arbetsnummer>813</Arbetsnummer>
  <Fakturanummer>20160813</Fakturanummer>
  <Köparens personnummer>19780412-XXXX</Köparens personnummer>
  <Uppgifter om arbetet>Städning</Uppgifter om arbetet>
  <Timmar>1</Timmar>
  <Materialkostnad>0</Materialkostnad>
  <Övrig kostnad>0</Övrig kostnad>
  <Betalningsdatum>20161207</Betalningsdatum>
  <Arbetskostnad>330</Arbetskostnad>
  <Betalt belopp>165</Betalt belopp>
  <Begärt belopp>165</Begärt belopp>
</1>
<2>
  <Arbetsnummer>776</Arbetsnummer>
  <Fakturanummer>ID</Fakturanummer>
  <Köparens personnummer>19530326-XXXX</Köparens personnummer>
  <Uppgifter om arbetet>Städning</Uppgifter om arbetet>
  <Timmar>1</Timmar>
  <Materialkostnad>0</Materialkostnad>
  <Övrig kostnad>0</Övrig kostnad>
  <Betalningsdatum>20161122</Betalningsdatum>
  <Arbetskostnad>390</Arbetskostnad>
  <Betalt belopp>195</Betalt belopp>
  <Begärt belopp>195</Begärt belopp>
</2>
<3>
```

I guess it´s some very obvious setting problem so I hope you guys can explain to me what I shall do to make it work otherwise I must input all the data manually which is a nightmare.
Many thanks in advance for spending your time on this issue!

Answer (score 1):

This is not well-formed XML because your element names contain spaces. The first instance of such an element is `<Köparens personnummer>`. It seems that the add-on that you downloaded is overly simplistic and assumes that wrapping a column name in XML markup is always going to work.

For your case, you are simply using a badly written tool and even if you fix this initial problem, there are probably going to be more problems down the road. The best way to proceed is to search for a better tool.

Comment: Moreover, numbers cannot be used as element names in XML. Sorry, but the tool you have downloaded is rubbish. It's not uncommon.

Comment: I've looked at the source code on github and it's garbage. Makes no attempt whatsoever to generate valid XML. Clearly never tested.